# How do I get HttpServletRequestObject in the @service class

Tags: spring, gwt, web.xml, gwt-rpc

I'm successfully able to integrate Spring and Spring4GWT.
Everything is working fine.

The only problem I'm facing is How do I get `HttpServletRequestObject` in the `@service` class?

Some of the configuration and code

### web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ui/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

### Service class

```
public class LoginServiceImpl implements ILoginService {

    private IUserService userService;
    public LoginServiceImpl(IUserService userService) {
        super();
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public boolean isAuthenticUser(String userName, String password) {
        // operation
    }
}
```

In `LoginServiceImpl` I'm not able to get the Servlet object.
I need it here so that I can use it for different purposes.

Any Idea?

Comment: What exactly are those different purposes?

Comment: Check out Spring Security, you don't want to re-implement something that is already existing and free to use.

Comment: I understand but in wide scope my question is about using HttpServletRequest object in GWT-RPC service.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I got a solution for it.
If someone wants to have access of the HttpServletrequest in the GWT-RPC service then the following can help.

### Modify web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/your_pattern/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

### In Service

```
ServletRequestAttributes sra = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes());
sra.getRequest();
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Note that as the URL pattern I use the same value as for my spring4gwt servlet

Answer (score 4):

From the design point of view, `you should NOT have a HttpServletRequest object in your service layer`. Instead, retrieve whatevet information you need from request and pass them as paramaeters to your service layer.

Please tell more about what you are trying to do and why you need a HttpServletRequest object in your service layer.

Otherwise your dependency hierarchy will have cycle. View layer depending service layer and service layer depending on view layer.

Comment: Its a GWT question. I don't want you to get confused. `LoginServiceImpl` is a servlet of type `org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet` which is handling all the request.

Comment: Well GWT design is that every service class should implement RemoteServiceServlet, so... But you are not wrong otherwise, also the "passing arguments as parameters" part is done by GWT-RPC framework.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the HttpServletRequest from your Controller to the Service Method (for example as method parameter).

Anyway:

- your Service Method should abstract from stuff like httpServletRequestObject. This abstraction is normally done in the (Web) Controller.
- it looks like you reinvent the security stuff, have you had a look at [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/)?

Answer (score 1):

There is also alternative solution, that might come handy when you also need `HttpServletResponse`.

Simply put:

- make your `ServiceImpl` classes to extend`org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet` (you should do it anyway)
- then alter the `SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet#getBean()` to return `this` object
- the `this` will be instance of your `ServiceImpl` extending `SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet` as long as your `web.xml` is refering to your `ServiceImpl` and not Spring4GWT directly. This is also standard GWT way, you can even automate it with [@RemoteServiceRelativePath](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/remoteservicerelativepath-annotation.html).
- you also want to run the servlet (the `this` object from above) through `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this)` to get your dependency injection done
- this way your `ServiceImpl` will also be the servlet responding to request and will be able to access [getThreadLocalRequest()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.html#getThreadLocalRequest--) from parent class

It is not that hacky as it looks. Basically GWT wants your service classes to be servlets and Spring4GWT want it to be standard Spring components. This approach is somewhere in between.