# How receive container managed security user principal without Java EE injection?

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have a Spring MVC controller and security is controlled using JDBC Realm from container managed security defined in Tomcat's `server.xml` and `<security-constraint>` tags in `web.xml`

How do I receive the user principal in Spring MVC controller? Is there some static context holder like in Spring?

Comment: I don't know Spring, but if there is a static `HttpServletRequest` holder (or you have access to the request), you can call `request.getRemoteUser()`

Comment: Thank you. Is there static solution? W/o request?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. How should that work anyway, this information is bound to a request. Does this question help: [How do I get HttpServletRequestObject in the @service class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6353656)

Comment: Please, https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE

Comment: That's funny, @BalusC...accourding to the people that work at Oracle, there is:  https://blogs.oracle.com/asabnis/entry/jee_app_vs_middleware_product and https://blogs.oracle.com/martinf/entry/jee_in_netbeans_with_glassfish

Comment: @CodeChimp: The change of the naming convenion happened relatively recently: compare J2EE v1.4 vs Java EE 5.

Comment: Also, @PavelBernshtam, have you tried adding a `Principal` to your controller's handler?  Not sure it will work in container managed security, but I don't see why not.

Comment: @Olaf, not arguing that.  Just pointing out that Oracle themselves sometimes say 'JEE', so I think bashing the OP for using it is a bit tryst.